# ggvis and rpivottable conflict in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis, rpivottable

I am plotting ggvis plot in one tab and generating a rPivottable in another tab.
If I add both to ui.R, I am unable to generate the Pivot table.

Below is a sample example.

```
app <- shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(navbarPage("v0.5",
                               tabPanel("Report",sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel(actionButton("bbutton","Generate Report")),
                                 mainPanel(rpivotTableOutput("myPivot"),verbatimTextOutput("mytext")))),
                               tabPanel("PLOT",sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel(actionButton("cButton","Plot")),#mainPanel()
                                 mainPanel(ggvisOutput("myPlot"))
                               )
                               )

)),
  server = function(input,output){
    observe({
      input$bbutton

      output$mytext <- renderText("Hello There")
      #mydata <- getPivotTableData()
      mydata <- mtcars


      output$myPivot <- renderRpivotTable({
        rpivotTable(data = mydata)
      })

    })
  }
)

runApp(app)
```

If I takeout the code

```
mainPanel(ggvisOutput("myPlot"))
```

and insert

```
mainPanel()
```

the pivot table is generated just fine.

I am using the following versions:
ggvis_0.4.2
rpivotTable_0.1.5.20

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a know bug due to difference in jQuery version used by ggvis and rpivottable. Download the latest version of ggvis from Github to resolve the issue. I am currently using the following version for rpivottable and ggivs and it works.
ggvis: ggvis_0.4.2.9000
rpivottable: rpivotTable_0.1.5.20

Comment: Correct.  Between htmlwidgets, ggvis and rpivottable conflicts arise with different jqueryui (the actual culprit) components and there is no final solution currently (it would have to be based on htmlwidgets).  With the latest github version of ggvis and the CRAN version of rpivotTable all should be ok.  Please let me know (on github) if / when we'll diverge again.